# SSRS fails to run on remote server but runs fine locally

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am having this issue since yesterday and have tried different things but is being difficult to know how to solve this issue, I have shared datasource and the same report works fine on my local machine but when I i Upload the report on the server and try to run o the server it gives me this error:

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet2'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

I have bben using this system for some time and never had this issue before, I dont think anything have been changed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing what the error message says?

```
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
```

It will probably be an error in the connection/query

Comment: @Charley, I can see I have to do this through Enable remote errors through SQL Server Management Studio

1.
Start Management Studio and connect to a report server instance. For more information, see Connect to a Report Server in Management Studio in SQL Server Books Online.

2.
Right-click the report server node, and select Properties. 

3.
Click Advanced to open the properties page. For more information, see Server Properties (Advanced Page) - Reporting Servicesin SQL Server Books Online.

4.
In EnableRemoteErrors, select True.

5.
 Click OK. 

But I cant find Enable option on my advanced tab

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337165.aspx#bkmk_ConfigurationInfo - you can do this via the SSRS database if you have access (look at the bottom of the page in the link) - change the ConfigurationInfo table in the report server database and restart the service. Is there any reason you can't get on the report server itself to run the report?

Comment: Thanks, the error I posted I got it when tried to run the report from the report server itserlf

Comment: I have enable it on the Configuration table but still not getting more information, getting exactly same error as before.

Comment: If you were to run it from the report server you should get the actual error message - are you sure you are logged on to the report server? e.g. via a terminal services session or physically?